# how to find index value from an unordered array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of numbers which is unordered list like this:-

```
 $a = array(
  '0' => '2',
  '1' => '4',
  '2' => '6'
  '3' => '8'
  '4' => '10'
);
```

Here, if i want to search number 8,then it should be return 
index value=3 
,but if i want to get value 3 which is not in array then it should return the nearest value

```
like 4= index value '1' and 2 =index value '0'.
```

How can i find this index value in `php`?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? We would like to see your efforts.

Comment: i have some logic like if any number wont found in an array then i can find out difference between them,but how to implement in php i didn't find out.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php


function array_search_closest($needle, $haystack)
{
    $closest = null;
    foreach( $haystack AS $key => $value )
    {
        if( $closest === null || abs($needle - $value) < $closest[0] ) 
            $closest = [abs($needle - $value), $key];
    }

    return $closest[1];

}

$array = [6,2,10,4,8];
echo array_search_closest(3, $array); //Output: 1
```

The basic functionality of that logic is to find the lowest absolute value between the needle and each of the items in the array. That value is stored into the `$closest` array.

The first iteration always sets the absolute value (we need something to check against). After that `$closest` is only overwritten if the absolute value between `$needle` and the value of the current iteration is lower than that of the last iteration. We eventually get lowest value, which we want.

We eventually return the key of that value.

*Note that `$closest` is actually an array. The first element represents the current closest value of the `$haystack` while the last element is the key that you want.*

Comment: You're welcome. A slight change could be made by adding a third parameter to decide wheter to take the high or the low distance to the given needle when both distances are the same. e.g. [2,4] and you're looking for **3**. Which one should be taken (both have the same distance). That might be something you want to implement.

Comment: Better than the other answer because it doesn't do unnecessary sorting.

Comment: Eduard, you're wrong about the benefit of using native functions rather than interpreted statements. The cost of sorting is meaningless as long as you have to parse the whole array.

Answer (score 1):

The trivial way to do it is the following:

```
function closest($array, $val) {
  $b=array_map(create_function('$v', 'return abs($v-'.$val.');'), $array);
  asort($b);
  return key($b);
}

echo closest(8); // returns 3
```

Comment: Awesome solution! Haven't even thought about `asort()`. For hipsters that could also come in closure-flavour instead of `create_function()` :D Joking aside. @neha you should use mark that as accepted answer, since it is much cleaner and also shorter than my solution.